# Windows App c# SQLlite Database Query

Tags: c#, sql, windows-store-apps, where-clause

Really new to SQL and I have spent days trying to do queries in my windows store app but can not get the where clause to work

I use the following code to query my database

```
    string query = string.Empty;
    public async Task<List<CityClass>> GetListCities(int fred)
    {
        List<CityClass> objLstCoty = new List<CityClass>();
        try
        {        
                query = "Select  " + DBColumns.Id + "," + DBColumns.WORKNUM +  "," + DBColumns.FAULTREF + " from " + DataBaseWrapper.Cities; 
                objLstCoty = await con.QueryAsync<CityClass>(query);
                tb1.Text = "ID: " + objLstCoty[fred].Id;
                tb2.Text = "Fault Ref: " + objLstCoty[fred].FAULTREF;
                tb3.Text = "Work Number: " + objLstCoty[fred].WORKNUM;
                 }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return null;
            throw ex;
        }
        return objLstCoty;

    }
```

This query 3 columns in my database and puts the data into 3 textboxs

How do I add a where statement so that it only returns the data where the `WORKNUM`  equals a certain number eg `WORKNUM = "112000"`

I Thought adding `+ " where " + DBColumns.WORKNUM = "112000";` would work but it does not

Any Help is appreciated

Mark

Comment: Saying _it doesn't work_ is no more helpful than going to the physician saying _doctor I'm feeling bad_ Please explain what doesn't work. What error message do you get if any?

Comment: Very sorry for that as the comment below shows the error I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how you would add that `WHERE` clause to the end of your query, it wouldn't even compile as the `=` sign is outside of the string you're building up.

Try doing the following:

```
query = "Select  " + DBColumns.Id + "," + DBColumns.WORKNUM +  "," + DBColumns.FAULTREF + " from " + DataBaseWrapper.Cities + " where " + DBColumns.WORKNUM + " = 112000";
```

Comment: Thank You very much the query went in but how do I now put the data in the textbox tb3.Text = "Work Number: " + objLstCoty[fred].WORKNUM; dosent work and I dont know what to change the variable fred to?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? If you debug through it, what's the value and type of `WORKNUM`?

Comment: Sorry As I said new to This and using other peoples code. WORKNUM is a number. in my old code I would specify a number in variable fred and this would bring back that record number what I am trying to achieve is to search on the WORKNUM  which is unique and only bring back that record so if the result of the query is say record 1000 i would put that into the variable fred to get the data unless there is a better way of doing it Hope I have explained it ok

Comment: Just as a side the database has over 10000 records and i am after which record has the column WORKNUM got the number 1000 in it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help guiding me in the right direction I managed to get it to work using

var ITEM = db.Query("Select * From Cities where WORKNUM='" + srcnum + "' ").FirstOrDefault();

where srcnum is the number i wanted to search for in the WORKNUM column

i can then just fill the textblocks using item.[columnname]

Mark